# Jersey client connection close memory leak issue

Tags: memory-leaks, connection, client, jersey, resource-leak

I am using Jersey v10 and have written the following code.Is this the right way to close a Jersey client connection to avoid memory leaks.I was not doing any calls int he finally before this.

```
ClientConfig config = setupHttps();
    final Client c = Client.create(config);

    final WebResource r = c.resource(baseUri);
    ClientResponse response = null;
    try {
        response = r.path("/....")
                .header("contentId", id)
                .header("sid", sid).get(ClientResponse.class);
        ...



    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Error returning contentServiceName.");

    } finally {
        if (response != null) {
            response.close();
        }
        if (c!= null) {
            c.destroy();
        }

    }
```

TIA,
Vijay

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I know, **yes, this is the right way to close a Jersey client** ... with the following caveats.

1) What you're trying to prevent is not memory leaks, but connection (to the server you're addressing) leaks ...

2) The following is written about the [Client](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.12/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/client/Client.html) class in [Chapter 3 of the Jersey Handbook](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/client-api.html#d4e623):

> Client instances are expensive resources. It is recommended a configured instance is reused for the creation of Web resources. The creation of Web resources, the building of requests and receiving of responses are guaranteed to be thread safe. Thus a Client instance and WebResource instances may be shared between multiple threads

Therefore, if you're planning on making multiple calls, it's a good idea **not** to call destroy for every call. The same (but to a lesser extent) is true for WebResources.

3) What I'm describing is from Jersey 1.1 (but I see [threads about this as far back as 2009](http://jersey.576304.n2.nabble.com/Best-practice-WebResource-td3477787.html)).